# Xcode Pod Error ld: framework not found Pods_APPNAMEHERE

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Im an android developer im trying to get started with ios development. Im using firebase on this project so i installed the pods needed however when i try to build the app (its empty for now) i get this error "ld: framework not found Pods_APPNAMEHERE"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer all i did was go to my list of linked frameworks and libraries and removed the framework that was there and replaced it with the pod file in my xcode project folder